# Can not detect ESC key in Cocoa Application?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsview, keyevent

I use onKeyDown in a Custom NSView in detect keydown events, it works well when I input the normal keys, like "a, b, c", but it does not invoke onkeydown function when I press ESC, I want to exit my application when user press ESC.

How to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, it turns out my keyboard is broken, only for ESC key, I changed with a keyboard, it works now. Thank you anyway.

Comment: This is actually hilarious.

Answer (score 2):

I just dropped in a KeyDown handler into a custom NSView in one of my test apps and the ESC key is hitting KeyDown perfectly fine.

Seems like something to do with the way you're calling KeyDown, I think?  Maybe the focus isn't set correctly.

In any event, another thing you can do is to implement `cancelOperation:` in your custom NSView.

Here is the documentation for [`[NSResponder cancelOperation:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSResponder/cancelOperation%3a).  This also responds to the Escape key and to the Macintosh standard Command + . key combination.

Also check out the ***Handling Key Events*** section of the [Cocoa Event-Handling Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingKeyEvents/HandlingKeyEvents.html), which is where I was looking for answers for you.  Hope this helps!